# Optimize performance to resize with maximum pixel value

Tags: python, image, resize

I want to reduce one size of an image by keeping only the maximum pixel value of each pixel set. I implemented this in python :

```
def pixel_max_resize(img, h, w):    
    imr = np.zeros((h,w),  dtype=np.uint8)
    r = int(h/w)    
    for j in range(0,w):
         imr[:,j] = np.amax(img[:,j*r:j*r+r], axis = 1) 
    return imr
```

This function is a lot slower than a cv2.resize of the same size (by a factor of 5-10). Anyone has an idea how to optimize the speed of this function ? Is there a list comprehension formulation that could speed up the process ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve since your code throws an error if the target height is not equal to the source height. Anyway, here is a function that resizes an image based on the maximum value of each subsample area. It's about 3-5 times faster than your code.

```
def pixel_max_resize(img, h, w):
    source_h, source_w = img.shape
    return img.reshape(h,source_h // h,-1,source_w // w).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(h,w,-1).max(axis=2)
```

(Caveat: source width and height must be an integer multiple of target width and height respectively)

**Explanation:**

The source 2d image is partitioned into a 3d array so that the first and second axis have the size of the target width and height and the third axis contains the values of all pixels to be subsampled for one target pixel. `max()` over this axis returns the maximum value for each subsample.

Comment: This is a genius solution for 2d tiling. The original image can be easily be reshaped slightly to match integer multiple between source / target.